# Configuración SQFLITE en flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

¿cómo puedo iniciar mi base de datos en el código de la carpeta del proveedor?
provider>db_provider.dart

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBProvider {

   static Database _database;
   static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
   DBProvider._();

   Future<Database> get database async {
     if(_database != null) return _database;

     _database = await initDB();

     return_database;
   }

   Future<Database>initDB() async {

   }

}
```

y tengo un error en el codigo estoy buscando la solucion, pero si alguien lo tiene por lo menos que me diga como puedo solucionarlo

Enviar comentarios
Paneles laterales

Comment: Probablemente _volviste a equivocarte de sitio_, estamos en [es.so] :) Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: En serio ? disculpeme es que estaba buscando la solución al código y soy nuevo en Stackoverflow no sabia que habia en español, pero igualmente gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que almacenar la Base de datos en el almacenamiento del dispositivo:

```
 Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Luego creas la ruta de la base de datos:

```
 String path = join(directory.path + '/' + 'repositorio.db');
```

Ya con esto podrías abrir la base de datos:

```
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 2, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
         await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_users("
          "id_user INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
          "name_user TEXT,"
          "lastname_user TEXT"
          ")");
```

initDB completo:

```
static initDB() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path + '/' + 'repositorio.db');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 2, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async { 
          await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_users("
              "id_user INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
              "name_user TEXT,"
              "lastname_user TEXT"
              ")");
  }
}
```

Comment: Se agradece la ayuda; aún así, la próxima vez, ¡aguardá a que el OP traduzca su pregunta!

Comment: muchas gracias, ya voy a implementarlo a mi codigo